# What does Instruments actually report?

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, instruments

Here is a small chunk of code I use in my game for grabbing memory usage information.

```
#include <mach/mach.h>

unsigned get_memory_bytes(void) {
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info( mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t) &info, &size );
    return kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ? info.resident_size : 0;
}

unsigned get_memory_kb(void) {
    return get_memory_bytes() >> 10;
}
```

Recently, I have been using Instruments to perform memory profiling in order to discover problems in my game's code. However, I notice a discrepancy between what my in-game report tells me and what Instruments tells me.

For more on that, [please go here](http://gikh.in/?p=115).

That said, I'm curious as to where Instruments pulls its information from. It supposedly attaches to the process, but it still has to grab the information from somewhere using something, so I'm wondering what that thing is and where it is being grabbed from.

Comment: I ended up doing a slight surgery to CCDirector to add a Mb line when displaying FPS etc ... using just about the same as your code. This i trust :)

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one using it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would expect Instruments does is that it [hooks into malloc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) (and related) functions to monitor all allocations.

I don't know for sure that this is what Instruments does, or whether it does anything above and beyond that. But it seems to be the most reasonable, fits-all-purposes, doesn't-miss-a-thing kind of solution a tool like Instruments would use.